# Choroplethr Multiple Border Colors

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

I'd like to let my choroplethr map have a different colored border around one (or several) of my counties.

I can change all the border colors or remove the border lines for all counties, but I can't figure out how to make just one county's border a different color. Sample code:

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(ggplot2)

data(county.regions)
montana.counties<-county.regions[county.regions$state.name=="montana",]

fakedata<-as.data.frame(montana.counties$region)
fakedata$value<-runif(n=56, min=0, max=1)
colnames(fakedata)[1]<-"region"

county_choropleth(fakedata,
                  state_zoom = c("montana"),
                  num_colors=1) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = value), color="black")
```

As an example, I'd love to be able to make the first county (region 30001) red, but keep the remaining counties' borders black. Does anyone have advice?

Answer (score 2):

Ari Lamstein was kind enough to post the answer to my question on another forum. I thought I'd add his reply to this post, since his function is an excellent solution. His response to my question:

> I did something similar in my article about the demographics of Ferguson, MO.
>
> http://www.arilamstein.com/blog/2015/07/02/exploring-the-demographics-of-ferguson-missouri/
>
> Can you look at the function highlight_county and tell me if that helps you?