# Object 'value' not found when trying to add border color to choroplethr county map

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

I want to add black borders to a county choropleth map I have created of New Jersey. Here is my current code:

```
    county_choropleth(tni_data,
                  state_zoom = "new jersey",
                  reference_map = TRUE,
                  num_colors = 8) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="YlOrRd") +
  labs(title = "DV/SV Incidents by New Jersey County",
       legend = "DV/SV Incidents (total)") + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=value), color="black")
```

Based on [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814878/choroplethr-multiple-border-colors).

I am getting this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'value' not found
```

Any advice on what might be wrong would be very appreciated!

UPDATE: Including minimal reproducible example!

```
tni_data <- structure(list(county = c("atlantic", "bergen", "burlington", 
"camden", "cape may", "cumberland", "essex", "gloucester", "hudson", 
"hunterdon", "mercer", "middlesex", "monmouth", "morris", "ocean", 
"passaic", "salem", "somerset", "sussex", "union", "warren"), 
    value = c(3187, 3410, 3747, 6532, 1339, 2510, 6420, 2417, 
    2656, 570, 2139, 4336, 3514, 1802, 4372, 2451, 773, 1840, 
    1265, 3054, 1311), region = c(34001, 34003, 34005, 34007, 
    34009, 34011, 34013, 34015, 34017, 34019, 34021, 34023, 34025, 
    34027, 34029, 34031, 34033, 34035, 34037, 34039, 34041), 
    county.fips.character = c("34001", "34003", "34005", "34007", 
    "34009", "34011", "34013", "34015", "34017", "34019", "34021", 
    "34023", "34025", "34027", "34029", "34031", "34033", "34035", 
    "34037", "34039", "34041"), state.name = c("new jersey", 
    "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", 
    "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", 
    "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", 
    "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey", "new jersey"
    ), state.fips.character = c("34", "34", "34", "34", "34", 
    "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", 
    "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34"), state.abb = c("NJ", 
    "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
    "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ"
    ), tni.per.capita = c(0.0120870785451511, 0.00365800545375359, 
    0.00841362616734292, 0.0128970859140997, 0.0145481806625452, 
    0.0167862660255339, 0.00803529522200319, 0.00828772853831489, 
    0.00395008261562097, 0.00458306196782208, 0.00582151702365076, 
    0.00525536262729346, 0.00567877891708886, 0.00366375585804471, 
    0.00720042952241982, 0.00488416303659037, 0.0123907990702893, 
    0.00559382733314282, 0.00900432777176698, 0.00548943903109783, 
    0.0124540454273419)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))

county_choropleth(tni_data,
                  state_zoom = "new jersey",
                  reference_map = TRUE,
                  num_colors = 8) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="YlOrRd") +
  labs(title = "DV/SV Incidents by New Jersey County",
       legend = "DV/SV Incidents (total)") + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=value), color="black")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimium reproducible example that I believe shows your situation:

```r
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)

# draw map to show "problem" - no borders on counties
county_choropleth(df_pop_county, state_zoom = "new jersey")
```

[image]

From your comment below, it sounds like you want to add a colored border to this map.

The key point is this: All choroplethr functions return ggplot2 objects. So while there is no parameter to county_choropleth like `set_border_color`, that's actually not a problem. We can add that border ourselves by writing code like the following:

```r
county_choropleth(...) + geom_polygon(...)
```

The complication is that is that the new layer (`geom_polygon`) needs its own data. And that data needs to be a map of NJ counties. Getting that map is a 2-step process:

### 1. Get a vector of NJ FIPS codes (AKA "regions")

You might not know this, but choroplethrMaps ships with a dataframe called `county.regions` that contains the FIPS code of every county in the US. We're going to use it to get the FIPS codes of every county in New Jersey.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data(county.regions)
nj_regions = filter(county.regions, state.name == "new jersey") %>% pull(region)

nj_regions
```

Note that choroplethr calls these `regions` because it's a neutral term that can be used with multiple geographies. I.e., whether dealing with states, counties, countries or zip codes, we can always use the term "region".

### 2. Subselect the county map to just NJ

You might not know this, but choroplethrMaps ships with the actual county map it uses to render the counties. It is called `county.map`. Now that we have the regions (i.e. FIPS codes) that we want to subselect, we can do so like this:

```r
data(county.map)

nj.county.map = filter(county.map, region %in% nj_regions)
```

### 3. Add the border as a new layer

And now we can add the NJ county map as a border with its own color. Note that we use `fill = NA` here to ensure that this layer is rendered as a border (and not filled in). Here I use yellow, but obviously you can change it as you see fit:

```r
county_choropleth(df_pop_county, state_zoom = "new jersey") +
  geom_polygon(data = nj.county.map, 
               aes(long, lat, group = group), 
               color = "yellow", 
               fill = NA, 
               size = 0.2)
```

[image]

As an FYI, I have created three, full-length courses on choroplethr (see [here](https://arilamstein.com/open-source/)). All are now free. They might help you as well.

I always wanted to create a fourth that dealt with issues like this: mixing choroplethr and ggplot2 to create custom maps. Questions like yours have come up quite a bit. One reason I'm giving such a detailed answer here is that I don't think I'll ever get around to creating a course like that. But hopefully this answer can help both you and the next person who has this question. The structure to these solutions tends to be the same: use the helper data structures (e.g. `county.map` and `county.regions`) in some custom way, and then add a new ggplot2 layer.

Comment: thank you for the response! I have added what I think is a minimal reproducible example to my question, please let me know if I need to add more (so that I know for the future). The functionality that I am looking for is a black border around each county, not around the entire state. Is that something that is possible with your package?

Comment: Yes, but I'll have to review the code to figure out how (I haven't look at it in years). Fundamentally, choroplethr was designed to just make it easier to make choropleth maps with ggplot2. That meant me deciding on sensible default options. Customizations like the one you want are possible (as you can do it with raw ggplot2), but it takes some know-how to to figure out how.

Comment: @SeanWallace I have edited my answer to include code that I think answers your question. If it does, can you please "accept" my answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick! Accepted! And I will be sure to check out your courses. Quick question: you said "You might not know this, but choroplethrMaps ships with the actual county map it uses to render the counties." I was wondering, what does it mean for the package to ship with the map?

Comment: @SeanWallace It was perhaps inartful phrasing on my part. What I wanted to emphasize is that most people who use choroplethr only know about the `<region>_choropleth` family of functions. I wanted to draw attention to the fact that for each of those functions, choroplethr also contains two data frames: `<region>.map` (the actual map) and `<region>.regions` (which contains multiple ways to refer to the formal region name that choroplethr requires). To solve your specific problem, you need to know about these objects.

Answer (score 2):

Did you define the term "value"? For colors/fills, you would need to have a categorization column of what you're basing color groups on.

So, for the example they linked, they defined `fakedata$value` as `runif(n=56, min=0, max=1)`. But that's to color in polygons.

If you just want a black border, I think `geom_polygon(aes(color = "black"))` should do it? It's difficult to tell without understanding what the data of tni_data looks like.

Comment: Thank you! That got rid of the error, but didn't create borders. Is there anything else I can share to help my question make more sense? Sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: Did you try switching the geom_polygon function as I noted above? Ari explained about reproducibility - basically, if we have the dataset, it's much easier to problem solve!